# How to call startManagingCursor in non activity Class or in any static method to retrive data from sqlite (in android)?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, static-methods

```
DBHelper db =new DBHelper(context);
Cursor result = db.weeklyMedicinesTaken();  
//WeeklyMedicinesTaken is a function in DBHelper class which returns cursor containing an integer value.
startManagingCursor(result);        //this function is a resistance in what i want to do.
      while(result.moveToNext())
     {
        int count=result.getInt(0); 
     }
 result.close();
```

Actually I have simple classes (non activity classes) in which i want to retrieve data from sqlite and apply some processing and evaluation of data., but the  problem is that the code above is working fine in activity but not working in any non activity class or in any static function of activity so that i can call that function from any class.

Any Suggestion Please??

Comment: Don't use `startManagingCursor`, because of the reasons in this post: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `getActivity().startManagingCursor(c)` or pass an instance of your context to the class inwhich you want to call `startManagingCursor()`

Lets say your class is sth like this:

```
Person{
Context mContext;
String name, surname;

Person (Context context){
mContext = context;
}
```

While creating your Person object you should pass the context like this:

in your `onCreate()` or somewhere else inside the activity:

```
Person p = new Person(getActivity());
```

However, it's not a good practice to manage your cursor outside the activity.
You can examine [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) for simple patterns.

Comment: still not working. can please u elaborate , 
how to  pass context to the class in the "startManagingCursor(cursor)" ??

and getActicity() is not accessible...

Comment: it means that sqlite database only used and accessed within activities?

I've so many classes which implement some algorithms to process data and return the result.  And these functions will not only be called from activity but will also be called by function of other non activity classes..

Is there not any way to write static function which can be called from any class. ?

Comment: You should examine content providers if you want a robust application. It's the best practice to communicate with your database: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html